# Would this work for venting a basement toilet?

Tags: basement, toilet, vent

I am putting a bathroom in my basement, but I am not sure about venting. I know studor vents are a possibility, but I would like to just tie into my existing system if possible. Here is a rough sketch of my proposal:[image]

Would this work, or do I need to bypass the 1st floor toilet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per any modern plumbing code (that I know of) you can't wet vent under a toilet. Once "soil" hits the stack, it's not a vent below that point.

So, you need a dry vent line, which can join the dry vent line above "6 inches above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served" so typically 40 inches or so, depending on (usually the highest fixture) sink flood rim height. Some folks run them all the way to the attic before joining, but that's not required under the codes I'm familiar with.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was hoping I was wrong. I will probably try to run a separate vent pipe connecting the toilet, sink, and washing machine in the basement, then run those up to the attic and see if I can tie it altogether up there.